# Convert Numpy array of ASCII codes to string

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to convert a NumPy array of integers representing ASCII codes to the corresponding string.
For example ASCII code 97 is equal to character `"a"`. 
I tried:

```
from numpy import *
a=array([97, 98, 99])
c = a.astype('string')
print c
```

which gives:

```
['9' '9' '9']
```

but I would like to get the string `"abc"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
print "".join([chr(item) for item in a])
```

**output**

```
abc
```

Comment: Thanks Ashoka for the nice solution. I was too focused on trying to use a NumPy function, but this seems like an elegant solution.

Answer (score 11):

Another solution that does not involve leaving the NumPy world is to view the data as strings:

```
arr = np.array([97, 98, 99], dtype=np.uint8).view('S3').squeeze()
```

or if your numpy array is not 8-bit integers:

```
arr = np.array([97, 98, 99]).astype(np.uint8).view('S3').squeeze()
```

In these cases however you do have to append the right length to the data type (e.g. 'S3' for 3 character strings).

Answer (score 7):

create an array of bytes and decode the the byte representation using the ascii codec:

```
np.array([98,97,99], dtype=np.int8).tostring().decode("ascii")
```

note that `tostring` is badly named, it actually returns bytes which happens to be a string in python2, in python3 you will get the bytes type back which need to be decoded.

Answer (score 6):

```
import numpy as np
np.array([97, 98, 99], dtype='b').tobytes().decode("ascii")
```

Output:

```
'abc'
```

[Data type objects (dtype)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

[tostring()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) is deprecated since version 1.19.0. Use [tobytes()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
from numpy import array

a = array([97, 98, 99])
print("{0:c}{1:c}{2:c}".format(a[0], a[1], a[2]))
```

Of course, `join` and a list comprehension can be used here as well.

Comment: But this *only works* for `len(a) == 3`, which seems very fragile.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i shoud've mentioned that i just wanted to show the "format()" method. Which could be used inside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions that rely on Python loops or string formatting will be slow for large datasets. If you know that all of your data are ASCII, a faster approach could be to use fancy indexing:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([97, 98, 99])
np.array([chr(x) for x in range(127)])[a]
# array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
```

An advantage is that it works for arbitrarily shaped arrays.