# How to convert numpy.int8 to string?

Tags: python, numpy

The below code tries to get ascii code from a 128 bit long numpy array.

```
st=""
ans_final=""

for i in range(len(key)):
  j=0
  while(j<8):
    st=st+ (key[i])
    j+=1
    i+=1
  ans=b_to_ascii(st)
  ans_final=ans_final+ans
```

In this code I am planning to pass a string of 8 bit long to b_to_ascii function which will return the ascii value of it, and then append all the ascii values together to get a string of 8 ascii values stored in ans_final.

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-5929c83ea390> in <module>()
      6   j=0
      7   while(j<8):
----> 8     st=st+ (key[i])
      9     j+=1
     10     i+=1

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int8") to str
```

Say the key here is stored like this-->

```
array([1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1], dtype=int8)
```

So after conversion to ascii the final answer will be `abc`.

In the first iteration of the code, what I want to do is, I want a string `st=11000010` passed to the function `b_to_ascii` which will return `a` which will get stored in `ans` and will be appended to the string `ans_final`. Similarly we will iterate the next 8 bits and remaining 8 bits to get `b` and `c` so the `ans_final` will become `abc`

So can anyone help me with how can I convert NumPy.int8 to string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Numpy array of ASCII codes to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838409/convert-numpy-array-of-ascii-codes-to-string)

Comment: Nope...............

Comment: What's the expected result in your example?

Comment: To return 16 character long ascii string..

Comment: What do you exactly try to achieve ? Can you give us some inputs and some wanted outputs ? Could you also give meaningful names to your variables ?

Comment: Which string exactly? As far as I know, you need 8 bits for each ascii character, so if you have 128 bits you will end up having a 16 characters long string

Comment: @imperosol.. Okay,,, I am editing and giving some example input outputs

Comment: @RiccardoBucco yes 16 characters, I miss-typed it.. edited

Comment: @GhostCat Will keep it in mind.. THanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `numpy.packbits` function (`arr` is your array of bits):

```
result = ''.join(map(chr, np.packbits(arr)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe string conversion in a comprehension, then `str.join()` method :

```py
for i in range(0, len(key), 8):
    s = ''.join(str(nbr) for nbr in key[i:i+8])
    ans = b_to_ascii(s)
```